# Primitive idempotent in semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I'm struggling to resolve an exercise in "Methods of Representation Theory" of Curtis & Reiner.

Let $A$ be a semisimple ring and let $e \in A$ an idempotent different from zero. Show that if $e$ cannot be written as the sum of 2 idempotents $f, f'$ different from zero such that $ff' = f'f = 0$, then the left ideal $Ae$ is simple. I took a left ideal $I$ non-zero, such that $I \subset Ae$ and I want to show that $Ae = I$. Since A is semisimple, there exists an idempotent $f$ such that $I = Af$ and another idempotent $f'$ such that $A = Af \oplus Af'$. Using that, I wrote $e = ef + ef'$ and I proved that $ef$ and $ef'$ are idempotents but I can't prove that $ef' * ef = 0$. Does someone see how to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: You are confusing yourself by using the same notation for two different things - you have written a decomposition into a sum idempotents: are they non-zero?

Comment: It depends on what idempotents you are talking, $e, f$ are non-zero, but I didn't supposed that $f'$ was non-zero.

Comment: And $ef$ cannot be equal to zero since it would imply that $f = 0$. If I can prove that $ef'*ef$ = 0, I know how to end the exercise, but I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Write $e=eg+eg'=f+f'$ using $I=Ag$ rather than $I=Af$ - you have established that $f$ and $f'$ are idempotents and $e$ is written as the sum of them.

Comment: Note that if $g'$ were zero, you would have $A=Ag$ (using my notation with $g$ for $f$ in the workings).

Comment: Ah - I see your issue - sorry I was being slow.

Comment: As $A$ is semisimple we can instead decompose $Ae=Af\oplus Ag$ for orthogonal idempotents $f,g$. Then  $e=f+g$.